# What's a good way to throw and handle events in PHP?

Tags: php, event-handling

I am just trying to get a general idea about the event prcessing mechanism in PHP5 in as neat way as possible. First of all I understand that a PHP application is not exactly a persistent type, so the events may not make a lot of sense, but from the OO perspective it might be a very elegant way to "communicate" between the objects.

So I am thinking that it would make sense to separate the events on the external events, such as `$_POST` & `$_GET` and the internal ones, i.e. function callbacks.

As far as the external ones, is it a good idea to process the `$_GET`s and `$_POST`s directly, or is it better to wrap them into an event of some sort?

Also, in order to process the internal events, do you have to pass the reference to the event handler/dispatcher to each class so they know how to throw them? I was thinking to use the PEAR EventDispatcher to do the work, but I am open to other suggestions.

Thank you!

Comment: If you are moving from system apps to web apps, look into MVC architecture. A good light footprint open source framework for this type of application is Codeigniter.

Comment: Yes, I am using the MVC, but I am thinking to use a separate EventHandler that could potentially either offload somework from or complement the controller

Comment: What you ask does not make much practical sense. I suggest reading the code of an existing framework to see how incoming query variables are handled, and then trying to write down some advantages that a scheme such as you propose would have. You 'll probably be hard pressed to find any.

Comment: wrapping superglobals in an event? what the heck are you talking about?

Comment: Jon & Joe, I don't really think that wrapping the $_POST & $_GET would make much sense either, but I threw the idea in the air because I've seen some folks in various forums talk about exactly that, even though I couldn't understand the value of doing that. But my general question about the events handling in PHP still stands, which, I do think, makes a lot of sense for various abstraction-type reasons.

Comment: You can set a universal exception handler for your application, if you want to. set_exception_handler . Set this at the beginning. Throw the exception from anywhere and it will be handled by this exception handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my point of view, HTTP events could or must be handle in a *Controller* layer type. Your domain/application/core/whatever name you call your domain rules MUST not depend of Sessions, Requests (post, get) and etc.

Model must be decoupled from any interface/controller dependencies i.e: buttons form names, interfaces process and so on.